# how to change dynamically yAxes in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I have a chart that I created in canvas using Chart.js I want to change yAxes dynamically according to some text, this line doesn't work, do I miss something?

```
  myChart.options.scales.yAxes.scaleLabel.labelString = "Test";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the scale title simply by updating the `labelString` value in your chart object's `options` property and calling the [`.update()`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) prototype method.

Assuming I have a chart instance called `myBar` (the instance is what is returned from the Chart.js constructor), then I can use the below example to change the y-axes title.

```
myBar.options.scales.yAxes[0].scaleLabel.labelString = "My New Title";
myBar.update();
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/VpmKrP) that demonstrates a working example of this.  Just click on the "Change Title" button to see if work.

Comment: well I found that I get an options undefined, when I look for it in browser console myChar.options, options is not recognized for a reason, I'll try your solution as well

Comment: well I tried your option and still I get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined